# How to install python-opencv without answering the quesitons?

Tags: docker, opencv

I'm trying to create a docker image (using a Dockerfile) and as part of the process, I have to install `apt-get install python-opencv`. But it asks all these questions about `geographic area` and other stuff. And I cannot answer them since it is within the process of creating a docker image. How can create a docker image with `python-opencv` without having to answer any questions?

```
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
  2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
  3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
```

Answer (score 7):

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install --yes python-opencv
```